# How do I implement a dispatch table for a text adventure game?

Tags: c#, adventure, dispatch-table

I am making a [text adventure in C#](http://code.google.com/p/escape-text-rpg/source/browse/Escape/), and someone suggested that I use a [dispatch table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dispatch_table) instead of a switch statement.

Here's the switch statement code:

```
        #region Public Methods
        public static void Do(string aString)
        {
                if(aString == "")
                        return;

                string verb = "";
                string noun = "";

                if (aString.IndexOf(" ") > 0)
                {
                        string[] temp = aString.Split(new char[] {' '}, 2);
                        verb = temp[0].ToLower();
                        noun = temp[1].ToLower();
                }
                else
                {
                        verb = aString.ToLower();
                }

                switch(Program.GameState)
                {
                        case Program.GameStates.Playing:
                                if (IsValidInput(Commands, verb, true))
                                {
                                        switch(verb) //this is the switch statement
                                        {
                                                case "help":
                                                case "?":
                                                        WriteCommands();
                                                        break;
                                                case "exit":
                                                case "quit":
                                                        Program.GameState = Program.GameStates.Quit;
                                                        break;
                                                case "move":
                                                case "go":
                                                        MoveTo(noun);
                                                        break;
                                                case "examine":
                                                        Examine(noun);
                                                        break;
                                                case "take":
                                                case "pickup":
                                                        Pickup(noun);
                                                        break;
                                                case "drop":
                                                case "place":
                                                        Place(noun);
                                                        break;
                                                case "use":
                                                        Use(noun);
                                                        break;
                                                case "items":
                                                case "inventory":
                                                case "inv":
                                                        DisplayInventory();
                                                        break;
                                                case "attack":
                                                        //attack command
                                                        break;
                                        }
                                }
                                break;

                        case Program.GameStates.Battle:
                                if(IsValidInput(BattleCommands, verb, true))
                                {
                                        switch(verb) //this is the other switch statement
                                        {
                                                case "attack":
                                                        //attack command
                                                        break;
                                                case "flee":
                                                case "escape":
                                                        //flee command
                                                        break;
                                                case "use":
                                                        //use command
                                                        break;
                                                case "items":
                                                case "inventory":
                                                case "inv":
                                                        //items command
                                                        break;
                                        }
                                }
                                break;
                }
        }
        #endregion
```

How do I refactor this to use a dispatch table?

Comment: You should have a look on [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/715457/how-do-you-implement-a-dispatch-table-in-your-language-of-choice), one of the answers shows a C# example that seems pretty correct, IMHO.

Comment: Before I would worry about that, I would focus on writing smaller more modular functions ;-)

Comment: @psycho This answered my question perfectly. You should post this as an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: @pst Could you give me an example of what to fix?

Comment: @ryansworld10 I would likely have each of the game-state logic in it's own function so that the branches (switches or dispatch or whatever) are not nested.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Simplest way would be to use a dictionary of delegates.

For example:

```
Dictionary<string, Action> dispatch = new Dictionary<string, Action>();

dispatch["help"] = new Action(() => Console.WriteLine("Hello"));
dispatch["dosomething"] = new Action(() =>
{
    // Do something else
    Console.WriteLine("Do Something");
});

// Call the 'help' command
dispatch["help"]();
```

For multiple different parameters it might be simplest to use a base Delegate and use dynamic Invoke.

```
Dictionary<string, Delegate> dispatch = new Dictionary<string, Delegate>();

dispatch["help"] = new Action(() => Console.WriteLine("Hello"));
dispatch["dosomething"] = new Action<string>(s => Console.WriteLine(s));

dispatch["help"].DynamicInvoke();
dispatch["dosomething"].DynamicInvoke("World");
```

And if using .NET 4 you can also use dynamic types to resolve at run time to reduce the clutter slightly of dynamic invoke.

```
Dictionary<string, dynamic> dispatch = new Dictionary<string, dynamic>();

dispatch["help"] = new Action(() => Console.WriteLine("Hello"));
dispatch["dosomething"] = new Action<string>(s => Console.WriteLine(s));

dispatch["help"]();
dispatch["dosomething"]("World");
```

Comment: This helps, but how would I pass arguments to the functions called in the actions>

Comment: @ryansworld10 See `Action<T>`, `Action<T1,T2>`, etc. (Both `Action` and `Func` come in many parameterized flavors, which are separate but related types.)

Comment: Alright I'm going to go with this one. It seems to be the simplest way to do it.

Comment: I'm still not quite understanding how to pass arguments to the statement stored in the dictionary (so I can tell the called method my noun).

Comment: I have added a few variants for you.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe he was refering to 'Double Dispatch', or the [Visitor Pattern](http://www.oodesign.com/visitor-pattern.html).

You could split up your code to improve a more 'dispatcher' style as follows:

```
public interface IGameState{
  void Help();
  void Question();
  void Attack();
}

public interface ICommand{
  bool IsValidFor(PlayingState state);
  bool IsValidFor(BattleState state);
  void Execute(IGameState state);
}

public class PlayingState : IGameState {
   public void Help(){ // Do Nothing }
   public void Question() { WriteCommands(); }

   private void WriteCommands(){ }
}

public class Battle : IGameState{
   public void Help(){ // Do Nothing }
   public void Question() { WriteCommands(); }
   public void Attack() { Roll(7); }

   private void Roll(int numDice){ }
}

public class CommandBuilder{
  public ICommand Parse(string verb){
    switch(verb){
       case "help":
         return new HelpCommand();
       case "?":
         return new QuestionCommand();
       case "attack":
         return new AttackCommand();
       default:
         return new UnknownCommand();
    }
  }
}

public class QuestionCommand(){
  bool IsValidFor(PlayingState  state){
     return true;
  }

  bool IsValidFor(BattleState state){
     return false;
  }

  void Execute(IGameState state){
     state.Question();
  }
}

public static void Do(string aString){
  var command = CommandBuilder.Parse(aString);
  if(command.IsValidFor(Program.GameStates))
     command.Execute(Program.Gamestates);
}
```

Comment: I have no clue what that means. And this doesn't answer my question of how to implement it.

Comment: I doubt it. A dispatch table is generally something something like a `Dictionary<string,Action>`, at least when I talk about it. The Visitor Pattern just inverts everything for the sake of OO.

Comment: I have updated my answer with how I would interpret the implementation in a more double-dispatch style.

Comment: Well, it is more of an object-oriented approach.  With this pattern, you keep your verb switching all in one place, and as your interfaces change - your code will break at build-time; rather than run-time.

Answer (score 1):

To take back @Jon Ericson's introduction :

A dispatch table is a data structure that associates an index (or key, read @pst's comment below) value to an action. It's a rather elegant replacement for a switch-type statement.

Concerning the implementation part, have a look on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/715457/how-do-you-implement-a-dispatch-table-in-your-language-of-choice) and particularly to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1056178/829728), which IMHO seems pretty correct but stays easy to understand.

Comment: An "index" might not be integral, as it often seems to imply. "key" is a more generic term, but not often used with arrays which can make suitable dispatch tables...