# Dynamic contract resolver based on route or type

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc-4, serialization, json.net

For a project I'm working on I'd like to camelCase the properties of an object being serialized back to the client-side JavaScript. I can [configure the API controllers to use](http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2013/03/25/asp-net-webapi-tip-3-camelcasing-json.aspx) the [CamelCasePropertyNameContractResolver](http://james.newtonking.com/json/help/index.html?topic=html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Serialization_CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver.htm) once at application startup (e.g. in `global.asax.cs`). This works for the case where I want this behavior across the entire web application.

The problem is that a number of areas of the web app are being worked on by other groups who have not yet converted their JavaScript to use the idiomatic camelCasing (they're using the unconventional PascalCase).

How can I create a contract resolver that will serialize via the default Json.NET implementation when the **CamelCasePropertyNameContractResolver**'s signature has but the single name parameter:

```
protected override string ResolvePropertyName(string propertyName)
{
    return propertyName;
}
```

yet camel case when I need it to? If there's a solution it would need, in short, some sort of context (e.g. a route, the type-being-serialized's namespace, ...) and some way to access that context in the contract resolver.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Custom Json.NET contract resolver for lowercase underscore to CamelCase](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18051395/custom-json-net-contract-resolver-for-lowercase-underscore-to-camelcase)

Comment: This is not a duplicate. I'm looking for something context aware, where the context could be based on the URL, the type, or something else. The question to which you refer addresses the mechanics but is not context aware.

Comment: Wouldn't adding the context as an argument to the default constructor do the trick? A [dispatch table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10436113/113722) would handle the context switching.

Comment: That would work except that the resolver is constructed once prior to all requests in `Global.asax.cs`, hence no context available.

Comment: @Kit ActionFilterAttribute allows you to appy custom resolvers on the Controller level see this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/14532163/3661